# How do I deal with "can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello I'm currently working on 4 combobox. When I check the whether combobox is returning the value of combobox it throws an tkinter exception.

I tried googling the problem and did some adjustment to code but none of them helped:

```
import sys
import tkinter.messagebox as box
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
else:
    import Tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.dict = {'Japan': ['Yokohama', 'Kobe', 'Tokyo'],
                     'China': ['Ningbo', 'Shanghai', 'Hefei'],
                     'USA': ['Baltimore', 'Long Beach', 'Chicago'],
                     'Russia': ['Moscow']}
        self.i = ["EXW", "FOB", "DAT"]
        self.c = ["40ton", "20ton", "Other"]

        self.variable_c = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_i = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_a = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.variable_b = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.last_county = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.area = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.country = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.incoterm = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.capacity = tk.StringVar(self)

        self.variable_b.trace('w', self.fun2)
        self.variable_a.trace('w', self.update_options)
        self.variable_i.trace('w', self.fun3)
        self.variable_c.trace('w', self.fun4)

        self.combobox_i = ttk.Combobox(self, values=list(self.i), 
        state='readonly')
        self.combobox_i.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.fun3)
        self.combobox_i.current(0)

        self.combobox_c = ttk.Combobox(self, values=list(self.c), 
        state='readonly')
        self.combobox_c.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.fun4)
        self.combobox_c.current(0)

        self.combobox_a = ttk.Combobox(self, 
        values=list(self.dict.keys()), state='readonly')
        self.combobox_a.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.fun)
        self.combobox_a.current(0)

        self.combobox_b = ttk.Combobox(self, values=self.dict['Japan'], 
        state='readonly')
        self.combobox_b.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.fun2)
        self.combobox_b.current(0)




        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Check", command=lambda : 
        sample(self.area, self.country, self.incoterm, self.capacity))




        self.combobox_i.pack()
        self.combobox_c.pack()

        self.combobox_a.pack()
        self.combobox_b.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.pack()

    def fun(self,*args):
        print("changed 1-st combobox value to: " + self.combobox_a.get())
        if self.last_county != self.combobox_a.get():
        self.combobox_b['values']=self.dict[self.combobox_a.get()]
        self.combobox_b.current(0)
        self.last_county = self.country = self.combobox_a.get()
        return self.variable_a.get()

    def fun2(self, *args):
        print("changed 2-nd combobox value to" + self.combobox_b.get())
        self.area = self.combobox_b.get()
        return self.variable_b.get()

    def fun3(self, *args):
        print("changed 3-rd combobox value to" + self.combobox_i.get())
        self.incoterm = self.combobox_i.get()
        return self.variable_i.get()

    def fun4(self, *args):
        print("changed 4-tth combobox value to" + self.combobox_c.get())
        self.capacity = self.combobox_c.get()
        return self.variable_c.get()


    def update_options(self, *args):
        countries = self.dict[self.variable_a.get()]
        self.variable_b.set(countries[0])

        menu = self.combobox_b['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')

        for country in countries:
            menu.add_command(label=country, command=lambda 
            nation=country: self.variable_b.set(nation))


def sample(area, country, incoterm, capacity):
    box.showinfo('info', 'Selected area: ' + area + '\nSelected country: 
    ' + country + '\nSelected incoterm:' + incoterm
      + '\nSelected capacity' + capacity)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

When I run the program and click the check button it shows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\IDL Mongolia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "D:/IDLMongolia's/Desktop/Project/Count_Incoterms.py", line 57, in 
<lambda>
self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Check", command=lambda : 
sample(self.area, self.country, self.incoterm, self.capacity))
File "D:/IDLMongolia's/Desktop/Project/Count_Incoterms.py", line 107, in 
sample
+ '\nSelected capacity' + capacity)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a string and `StringVar`. To get the string from the `StringVar` use the `get` method.

The neatest way to do this is to call `get` when you pass the strings to `sample`. That way sample doesn't need to know about `StringVar`s.

```
sample(self.area.get(), self.country.get(), self.incoterm.get(), self.capacity.get()))
```

I'd look for an issue elsewhere in your code, as one of these `StringVar` variables is being assigned to from a string. It's causing an exception if you change the options then click the check button.

There are other issues in your code for sure, but this resolves the one in the question.

Comment: yes thats what I was predicting in the last part of my answer. In your functions `fun2`, `fun3` etc you assign a different type to the variable. So it did have a get method when it was a `StringVar` but when you assigned a string to it, it lost that method. You should just use strings unless you need to use the `StringVar`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory - You are trying to concatenate a `StringVar` object with a string.

Normally you need to use the `get` method on a `StringVar` to retrieve its value. But I noticed that you actually don't even need a `StringVar` nor had you set or altered their values in any means.

To properly fix your error - Just don't create the `StringVars` at the first place. Instead, make them a blank string.

```
class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        ...
        self.area = ""
        self.country = ""
        self.incoterm = ""
        self.capacity = ""
```

What I really recommend though, is to not create the dummy variables at all. You can always retrieve the values directly though `combobox.get()'.

```
class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        ...
        #self.area = ""
        #self.country = ""
        #self.incoterm = ""
        #self.capacity = ""

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="Check", command=lambda : sample(self.combobox_a.get(), self.combobox_b.get(), self.combobox_i.get(), self.combobox_c.get()))

        ...
```

Comment: Thanks It helped but now the program works but there is no default value for each combobox

Comment: If all you do to get the value of the `ComboBox` - you can also skip the part to create the empty strings. Use `combobox.get()` to retrieve the combobox value as string directly.